# simple_html_dom does not store changes

Tags: simple-html-dom

I need to execute some consecutive actions using [simple_html_dom](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/), that seems not working, without saving the results of the previous action. So let's say this is the first action:

```php
$html = str_get_html('<span class="a">a</span>');

if($elem = $html->find('.a', 0))
{
    $elem->innertext = '<span class="b">b</span>';
}
```

This works fine, and now the text content of `$html` is `<span class="a"><span class="b">b</span></span>`. Now I execute the next action, that is:

```php
if($span = $html->find('.b', 0))
{
    $span->innertext = 'c';
}
```

This does not work, unless I save before the results of the first action, writing:

```php
$html = str_get_html($html->save());
```

But doing that more times, slows the execution time very much.

I also tried to replace the first action with the following code:

```php
if($elem = $html->find('.a', 0))
{
    $span = $html->createElement('span', 'b');
    $span->addClass('b');
    $elem->appendChild($span);
}
```

But the second action still does not work. Is there a solution?

Thanks